# Wildcard for domain URL in if statement (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to hide a particular div (id=contactinfo) on the page when the current URL ends in `/folder1/`. For example:

```
http://example.com/folder1/
https://example1.net/FOLDER1/
example2.org/Folder1/
example3.com/folder1/
subdomain.example.com/folder1/
intranet/folder1/
```

Here's what I have, which doesn't hide the div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.href.toLowerCase() == "[^ ]*/folder1/".toLowerCase()) {
        document.getElementById("contactinfo").style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("contactinfo").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

I'm new to JavaScript and suspect there might be a problem with using regex in a literal comparison. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "suspect there might be a problem with using regex in a literal comparison" — Well. Yes. How about typing "JavaScript regular expression" into Google and finding out how to use regular expressions properly?

Comment: You should use the test method of regular expressions :
http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why regex ...?

You want to know if the current path ends in `/folder1‌​/`, regardless of case - so let's do just that, get the last 9 characters of the lower-cased path, and do a simple string comparison:

```
window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().substr(-9) == '/folder1‌​/'
```

---

The "condensed" version, this is all you need if you want to keep it short:

```
document.getElementById('contactinfo').style.display = 
  (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().substr(-9) == '/folder1‌​/' ? 'none' : 'block');
```

(`()` optional, but they add a bit of readability.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp` `/folder1/i`, note the case insensitive flag, `RegExp.prototype.test()` which returns a `Boolean` and `.pathname` of `location`

```
if (/folder1/i.test(location.pathname)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions in JavaScript aren't just strings, but are encapsulated in `/` like this:

```
const regex = /\/folder1\/?$/i
```

Note the `$` in the RegEx. It makes the regex match only if the `folder1` is at the end and the `?` makes the last slash optional. The `i` at the end denotes that uppercase or lowercase doesn't matter.

You can compare the current URL against that regex by running

```
regex.test(window.location.href)
```

which will return true if the regex is matched. So you'll end up with:

```
if (/\/folder1\/?$/i.test(window.location.href)) {
  document.getElementById("contactinfo").style.display="none";
} else {
  document.getElementById("contactinfo").style.display="block";
}
```